# persisting variable value in unit testing in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm just getting started doing some unit testing in vs2010.  I have a test method that sets a private int variable and then a couple of other test methods that attempt to use that variable.  The variable does correctly get set when the first test executes but when it then moves to the next test the variable is reset to 0.  How can I keep the value of that variable for all tests?  Here's some example code.

```
public MyClassFixture{
  private Controller controller;
  private int id;

  public MyClassFixture(){
    controller = new Controller();
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void Should_Generate_New_Id(){
    id = controller.GenerateNewId();
    Assert.IsTrue(id > 0);
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void Should_Get_New_Record(){
    var record = controller.GetNewRecord(id);
    Assert.IsNotNull(record);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why? The whole point of unit testing is that tests must be independent from each other. And this is exactly what MSTest is doing - running tests independently so that `id` is always resets.

Comment: That makes sense.  But I thought you could also set up initialization routines for these purposes?  And, I also thought each test was only supposed to test one thing.  If that's the case then how do I test generating the new id, getting the associated record, updating it and deleting it.  Wouldn't I need separate tests for each creating the need to keep track of the id?  Thanks.

Comment: I guess you will have to call `Should_Generate_New_Id` from other tests and change it to return int. If it's convenient for you to have the same id in all tests then you could consider `get,update,delete` as one test, or mock `GenerateNewID` to force it to return special id.